# .htaccess get 3rd level folder file content to 2nd level folder file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to point

http://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php

to

http://example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/folder3/(.*)$ http://{%HTTP_HOST}/folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

This code redirects 
from: `folder1/folder2/folder3/another_foler/or_another_file.php?and=get`
to:   `folder1/folder2/another_foler/or_another_file.php?and=get`

So same link, but without `folder3`.